# How to get User and Group Details using Query in Adobe CQ5

Tags: adobe, aem, query-builder

How can we pull the User and group details using Query in CQ5?

Comment: Can you precise your question? Do you need to query for a specific user or group? Or a do you want a list of users and groups that match particular criteria?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the querybuilder to find a list of users and groups in JSON format:

Users:

```
http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?property=jcr:primaryType&property.value=rep:User
```

Groups:

```
http://localhost:4502/bin/querybuilder.json?property=jcr:primaryType&property.value=rep:Group
```

The key parameters of both of these queries are the property and property.value.  They specify the property name we are searching (jcr:primaryType) and the values we are searching for (rep:User and rep:Group respectively.

These queries will give you back a list of the matching nodes that looks something like this:

```
{
  success: true, 
  results: 10,
  total: 11,
  offset: 0,
  hits: [
  {
    path: "/home/groups/u/user-administrators",
    excerpt: "",
    name: "user-administrators",
    title: "user-administrators",
    created: "2013-06-14 10:50:39"
  }, 
  ...
  ]
}
```

You can find more information on querybuilder here:
http://www.slideshare.net/alexkli/cq5-querybuilder-adapttoberlin-2011

This will show you how to restrict your query by adding further criteria.

Comment: also be aware that it is very dangerous to leave the querybuilder open in a production environment since it allows anyone to insert queries.